# Javascript if statement says 63>542 is true

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm doing code wars, and I cannot understand why the code below doesn't work as I want it to work.

The best is if I remove 63 it works.

```
function low(numbers){
      var arr = numbers.split(" ")
      var highest = numbers[0];
      for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] > highest){
          console.log(arr[i] +">"+ highest)
          console.log(arr[i] > highest)
          highest = arr[i]
        }
      }
      return highest
    }

    low("4 5 29 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 3 4 63 -6");
```

Comment: You're comparing strings, not numbers.

Comment: You're comparing strings

Comment: Alphabetically, "6" is higher than "5".

Comment: All the commenters are correct, you need to use `parseInt(arr[i], 10)`,  `var highest = parseInt(numbers[0], 10);`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must using parseInt:

```js
function low(numbers){
      var arr = numbers.split(" ")
      var highest = parseInt(numbers[0]);
      for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(parseInt(arr[i]) > highest){
          console.log(arr[i] +">"+ highest)
          console.log(parseInt(arr[i]) > highest)
          highest = parseInt(arr[i])
        }
      }
      alert(highest)
      return highest
    }

    low("4 5 29 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 3 4 63 -6");
```

Comment: I wrote the part that must be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings. "63" > "542" is true. Try and cast to integer.